# Project a vector onto the intersection of surfaces

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I want to project a vector $\vec v$ onto a surface $S$ defined as the intersection of other surfaces. For example, in 5-dimension I have the surface $S(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=c$, defined by the intersection of the two surfaces

$g_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c_1 \quad$ with $ \quad x_4, x_5$ vary freely

$g_2(x_1,x_4,x_5)=c_2 \quad$ with $ \quad x_2, x_3$ vary freely

I don't want to compute the intersection surface $S$ because it may be impossible for higher dimensions.

At first I thought I could simply project the vector on the two subspaces $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ and $\{x_1,x_4,x_5\}$, ie. on each surface $g_1$ and $g_2$, and take the reunion of all projection. But it is wrong because the surfaces $g_i$ are not the projection of S.

Any ideas, or relevant literature?
Thank you.

*I am currently thinking about something : let suppose we deal with planes, as pictured bellow. I want to project a vector $\vec v$ on their intersection line (green line). Each plane is defined by two vector director. If the two planes intersect, they must have a common vector director ($\vec u_1 = \vec u_2 = \vec u$ on the picture). I project $\vec v$ on each subspace, giving $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$. Finally, I project each $\vec v_i$ on $\vec u$, and sum the results.*

*Or equivalently, directly project $\vec v$ onto $\vec u$.*

*Well, it is not quite satisfying as it requires to find $\vec u$, which seems to me to be equivalent to find the intersection, which I don't want.*

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your notation and terminology: "$S(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=c$" seems to refer to a four-dimensional object (a level set of a function $S$), but by "$g_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c_1$" do you mean a two-dimensional surface in the three-dimensional subspace $\{x_4=x_5=0\}$, or the four-dimensional level set on which $x_4$ and $x_5$ vary freely? If the former, could you explain exactly how $S$ is defined by the equations $g_1(x_1,x_2,x_3)=c_1$ and $g_2(x_1,x_4,x_5)=c_2$?

Comment: By "g1(x1,x2,x3)=c1" I mean "the four-dimensional level set on which x4 and x5 vary freely".
I changed the formulation, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks; that clarifies. :) One other issue: Presumably the vector $v$ is given/known. Are you also given a point $p$ of $S$, and you want the component of $v$ tangent to $S$ at $p$? (If so, as I'm guessing, your question has a straightforward algorithmic solution using calculus and linear algebra, which I'll sketch out if no one beats me to it.)

Comment: Right :) I take a known vector $\vec v$, at a point $p$ of $S$, and I want the component of $\vec v$ tangent to $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be a point of $S$ and $v$ a vector based at $p$. The algorithmic solution to your question has two phases: Describe the set $T_{p} S$ of vectors tangent to $S$ at $p$, and project $v$ into $T_{p} S$.

Here's a general sketch (including technical hypotheses that are "almost certainly true in real situations"): Suppose $S$ is defined by $m$ equations in $n > m$ variables; precisely, assume $S$ is a regular [level set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) defined by equations
$$
g_{i}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = c_{i},\quad i = 1, \dots, m,
$$
in which the function $g_{i}$ have continuous first partial derivatives and the gradient vectors $n_{i} = \nabla g_{i}(p)$ are linearly independent. The tangent space $T_{p}S$ is the set of vectors $x$ satisfying $\langle n_{i}, x\rangle = 0$ for all $i$. This is a homogeneous linear system of $m$ equations in $n$ variables. A basis for the set of solutions can be found by "standard linear algebra techniques" ([Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)).

Once you have a basis $\{w_{1}, \dots, w_{n-m}\}$ of $T_{p} S$, use the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to construct an [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) $\{u_{1}, \dots, u_{n-m}\}$ of $T_{p} S$. The desired projection is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-m} \langle v, u_{j}\rangle u_{j}
  = \langle v, u_{1}\rangle u_{1} + \dots + \langle v, u_{n-m}\rangle u_{n-m}.
$$
The final formula is essentially trivial to work with; the "hard part" is to calculate an orthonormal basis of $T_{p} S$.

**Example:** Suppose $S$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
g_{1}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{5})
  &= (x_{1} - 1)^{2} + x_{2}^{2} - (x_{3} - 1)^{2} = 0, \\
g_{2}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{5})
  &= x_{1} + x_{4} + x_{5} = 0,
\end{align*}
and $p = (0, \dots, 0)$ is the origin. The respective gradients are
\begin{align*}
\nabla g_{1} &= \bigl(2(x_{1} - 1), 2x_{2}, - 2(x_{3} - 1), 0, 0\bigr), \\
\nabla g_{2} &= (1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
\end{align*}
and the gradient vectors at $p$ are
$$
n_{1} = (-2, 0, 2, 0, 0),\quad
n_{2} = (1, 0, 0, 1, 1).
$$
The resulting system of equations $\langle n_{i}, x\rangle = 0$ has coefficient matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}rcccc@{}}
-2 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right].
$$
Gaussian elimination converts this to the reduced row-echelon matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}ccccc@{}}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right],
$$
from which we can solve for $x_{1}$ and $x_{3}$ in terms of the free variables $x_{2}$, $x_{4}$ and $x_{5}$:
$$
x_{1} = -x_{4} - x_{5},\quad
x_{3} = -x_{4} - x_{5}.
$$
Successively setting each free variable to $1$ and the other free variables to $0$ gives a basis of $T_{p} S$:
$$
w_{1} = (0, 1, 0, 0, 0),\quad
w_{2} = (-1, 0, -1, 1, 0),\quad
w_{3} = (-1, 0, -1, 0, 1)
$$

Now orthonormalize. Gram-Schmidt gives
\begin{align*}
u_{1} &= w_{1}, \\
u_{2} &= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} w_{2}, \\
u_{3} &= \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{15}}(1, 0, 1, 2, -3).
\end{align*}

Finally, if $v = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, v_{4}, v_{5})$ is an arbitrary vector at the origin, its projection into $T_{p} S$ is
\begin{multline*}
\langle v, u_{1}\rangle u_{1}
  + \langle v, u_{2}\rangle u_{2} + \langle v, u_{3}\rangle u_{3} \\
  = v_{2} u_{1} 
  + \left(\tfrac{-v_{1} - v_{3} + v_{4}}{\sqrt{3}}\right) u_{2}
  + \left(\tfrac{v_{1} + v_{3} + 2v_{4} - 3v_{5}}{\sqrt{15}}\right) u_{3} \\
  = v_{2} (0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
  + \left(\tfrac{-v_{1} - v_{3} + v_{4}}{3}\right) (-1, 0, -1, 1, 0) \\
  + \left(\tfrac{v_{1} + v_{3} + 2v_{4} - 3v_{5}}{15}\right) (1, 0, 1, 2, -3).
\end{multline*}

Comment: Very nice. It helps, a lot thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome. :)