# project a point onto the intersection of surfaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, nonlinear-optimization

I have several non linear equations $g_i$ that represent surfaces $s_i$. Their intersection form the surface $S$.

For example

$s_1 : g_1(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=c_1$

...

$s_n : g_m(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=c_m$

$S=s_1 \cap s_2 \cap ... \cap g_n$

Now I want to project a point $P$ onto $S$. I wish to find and algorithmic procedure. If one knows the surface $S$ equation it is trivial, because we just need to follow the gradient until we reach the right level set. But for this case I don't find.

It maybe looks a bit like [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887032/project-a-vector-onto-the-intersection-of-surfaces)

Note: I don't want to use some analytic approach using linear algebra that I can find in optimization textbook, because I am going to deal with a huge number of surfaces, so I will never be able to solve the matrices.

Thank you

Comment: Do you want the point on $S$ closest to $P$ (which is usually what is meant by projection) or just any point on $S$? Because the "follow the gradient" procedure you mentioned doesn't necessarily give you the closest point.

Comment: Anyway, you can try following the gradient of $\big(g_1(\vec x)-c_1\big)^2+\cdots+\big(g_m(\vec x)-c_m\big)^2$.

Comment: Not necessarily the closest point. Can you explain the gradient you proposed? Why square?

Comment: It's a sum of squares, so the minimum is attained when all the terms are zero, i.e. $g_1(\vec x)-c_1=0,$ $\ldots,$ $g_m(\vec x)-c_m=0$.

Comment: I see, very straightforward

Answer (score 0):

The projection is defined as the point $X=(x_1,x2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that solves

$\min || P - X ||^2$

$s.t.$

$ g_i(X) = c \quad \forall i=1,\ldots,m$

which can be trivial or extremely difficult depending on the constraint set. The solution is not even unique in general. If $g_i$'s are convex functions, than you can somehow solve efficiently. Otherwise you end up in a global optimization problem.